# How to rename a sequence in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I need to rename the sequences of my tables. There are a lot of tables and they are complex and droping anything would not be prefered. Is there a way to rename them?

I tried:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE ISEQ$$_149698 RENAME TO NEW_SEQUENCE;
RENAME ISEQ$$_149698 to NEW_SEQUENCE;
```

The first option throws the following error:

```
SQL Error [2286] [42000]: ORA-02286: no options specified for ALTER SEQUENCE
```

The second:

```
SQL Error [32799] [99999]: ORA-32799: cannot rename a system-generated sequence
```

Comment: If the sequences are system generated (like to support an identity column), then you can't rename them.

Comment: why do you think you should rename a sequence?  Especially a system generated one?  What _business_ problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My guess is that OP is diffing the schemas of two different databases and the system-generated sequences mess that up. At least that's why I wish I could rename system-generated sequences.

Comment: No functional reason behind it. The client has such db naming conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot rename a sequence generated for an identity column. (As other users have pointed out, and as the error message implies.) For that reason, I recommend you use a sequence default value instead of an identity column.

For example:

```
--Create the sequence and a table to use it.
create sequence my_sequence;
create table my_table(a number default my_sequence.nextval, b number);

--Rename the sequence to whatever you want.
rename my_sequence to my_sequence2;
```

However, there are a few disadvantages of the default approach:

1. This feature is not available until 12.1. (Although identity columns are also a new feature.)
2. You have to create the sequences yourself (obviously).
3. You need to remember to also grant the sequence to any users who will insert rows to the table:

```
grant insert, select on my_table to test_user;
grant select on my_sequence to test_user;
```

4. If you rename a default sequence you must also modify the default value to point to the new sequence.

```
--After a sequence rename, this INSERT fails with: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
insert into my_table(b) values(1);

--You must first modify the table:
alter table my_table modify a number default my_sequence2.nextval;

--Now this will run:
insert into my_table(b) values(1);
```

Despite the disadvantages of using the sequence default, I still prefer that approach over identity columns because I want all of my objects to have the exact same name in every environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Too bad I can not rename the sequences. Looks like recreating the tables with custom sequences is the only solution

Answer (score 0):

```
rename old_seq to new_sequence;
```

Comment: As I said. I tried it and it threw this error:
SQL Error [32799] [99999]: ORA-32799: cannot rename a system-generated sequence

Comment: Your question REFERENCES a sequence not an IDENTITY column. As PMDBA said above these cant re renamed. I'm curious why do they need to be renamed

Comment: I need to rename them, because the client has some standards that need to be respected. Too bad they can not be renamed.

Comment: I understand your problem but these should be invisible to your client and they shouldn't be referencing those names only the column name ie seq_num, which I put in everyone if my tables. Hope it works out for you